# Explain the PHP code & exit() function

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo "My name is ";
writeName();
exit();
function writeName() { echo "MY NAME"; }
```

Why the exit(); not working ?
Code output is: **My name is MY NAME**.

Comment: The code is working exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will create your function regardless of the `exit()`. Then, you call `writeName()` before the `exit();` so it behaves as expected. (outputs and dies)

try this:

```
<?php
echo "My name is ";
writeName();
exit();

echo 'I am still alive!';

function writeName() { echo "JEWEL AHMMED"; }
```

and the "I am still alive!" will not be output.

Comment: Thanks :) When I created the topic I was very new in PHP, Now I understood it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The function `writeName()` is being called before the script is being exited. Therefore it will still look for the function, even though it's defined after your exit.

If you were to call the function `writeName()` again, this time *after* your `exit()`-call, it won't output anything.

Comment: I would +1 but I don't want to encourage this type of question.

Comment: Same here. I made it as a comment, but deleted it soon after.

Comment: Thanks Padarom, Now I understood.

Answer (score 0):

PHP separates the act of compiling and the act of execution. The entire code is compiled, *including code that follows any calls to* `exit()`, and *then* the code is executed.